# Validate login credentials using EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, office365api

Is there a way to validate login credentials provided by a user using EWS Managed API without sending an email. I am using AutodiscoverUrl method on an [ExchangeService] object but it takes too long? Any suggestion would be appreciate it.

```
        try
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxx@yyy.com", "password");
            service.AutodiscoverUrl("xxxx@yyy.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);    

            Console.WriteLine("Credentials validated successfully");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to get this up to speed, not nice but it works, is to set the service url yourself. 
First get the exchange service url by running the autodiscoverurl method in debug mode:

[image]

Then instead of running autodiscoverurl method on the service, add the url you got from the autodiscoverurl method:

```
 service.Url = new Uri("https://yourExchangeURL.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

Instead of calling autodiscover to verify user credentials, you can make a request on the mail account ([Check exchange credentials remotely and check user logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381378/check-exchange-credentials-remotely-and-check-user-logged-in))

```
var findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0), new FolderView(10));
```

Your final code will then look like this

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013_SP1);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("xxxx@yyy.com", "password");
service.Url = new Uri("https://yourExchangeURL.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
var findFolderResults = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0), new FolderView(10));
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, Thanks. well, what i am actually trying to do is use AutodiscoverUrl to validate that the credentials of the user are correct, if not that method trigger an exception that I can catch to know that. If I do not use that method I can not validate those credentials. I looking for a way to do it without using AutodiscoverUrl because it is slow.

Comment: Edited my answer so it verifys the credentials @D.B

Comment: Thanks Marcus. It was great help.