# How to set Time out to AutodiscoverUrl call using EWS in C#?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am working on Mail Application. I want to set time out for server call of log in using EWS. I have already set 15 seconds for time out but sometimes it takes 1 minutes or more.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = CertificateValidationCallBack;

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
service.TraceEnabled = true;
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(email, Pwd);
service.Timeout = 15000;
service.AutodiscoverUrl(email, RedirectionCallback);
//some times it takes 1 minutes to call (1 minute to reach next statement)
EWS_URL = service.Url.ToString();


//check for certificate
private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
        object sender,
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    if ((sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None))
    {
        entityExchangeServer.isValid = true;
        return true;
    }

    // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
    if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
    {
        if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
        {
            foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
            {
                if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
                   (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
                {
                    // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
                    {
                        // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
                        // so the method returns false.
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
        // untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
        // for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // In all other cases, return false.
        return false;
    }
}

static bool RedirectionCallback(string url)
{
    return true;
}
```

I have already set 15 seconds for time out but sometimes it takes 1 minutes or more.

Can anybody please suggest how to set time out here?

Comment: If it's not that likely your organization will change their exchange server DNS in the near future, then add the URL directly to the service instead of doing autodiscover on the service.Totally worth it. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587942/validate-login-credentials-using-ews-managed-api/36589802#36589802

Comment: @MarcusH I have both options. If user knows `service.Url `, he can enter URL and that will be easier and faster. But if user doesn't know `service.Url `, he will just enter their username and password. I must go for AutoDiscover in that case. Please suggest your thoughts

Comment: @MarcusH I know AutoDiscover is headache sometimes if Server is down. I am surprise why TimeOut is not working in case of AutoDiscover. It should work.

Comment: Ok, then I understand the context here. The timeout functions is not something I've worked with before but I'll do some searching and get back to you if I found anything.

Comment: Judging from the [Source](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api) you cant specify any timeout

Comment: @CSharpie It should have time out as it is the only way to stop the service call after some limited time else it will keep loading till service call returns. Don't you believe my currently my server is down and it takes 2 minute for a single AutoDiscover call.

Comment: Im not saying that it doesnt have any, im saying you cannot specify it.