# EWS AutoDiscoverUrl through CITIX

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

The following code does not seem to work when I am connected to our network via CITRIX, offsite.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);

WebCredentials wbcred = new WebCredentials("myuser", "mypassword", "mydomain");
service.Credentials = wbcred;

   try
   {
    service.TraceEnabled = true;
    Console.WriteLine("Attempting to autodiscover Url...");
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("myuser@mydomain.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
   }

   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(ex);
   }

EWSConnection.SetStreamingNotifications(service);
```

No error is caught, and I get no response it just hangs indefinitely.

If I browse to this URL however, I can see the ErrorCode 600 and Invalid Request response from the service.

https://autodiscover.mydomain.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

When I am on site and not connected via CITRIX, these lines of code run as expected, it's just when I am going through CITRIX nothing comes back.

Why is this happening?

Comment: If I bypass the AutodiscoverUrl request as per this Q/A then I can establish a connection, however I am still curious as to why this service is not available over citrix or similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587942/validate-login-credentials-using-ews-managed-api/36589802#36589802

Comment: What does the Trace show ? it shouldn't hang as such because the requests should timeout after 90 seconds. At a guess it maybe issue with SSL negotiation you really need to run the code is a debugger or try some framework tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs6s4h68(v=vs.110).aspx